# how to add Section Insect in collection view programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to add Section Insets to my collection view based on "Left Aligned collection View Flow Layout"

I have use following code but not working,

```
  @IBOutlet private weak var collection: UICollectionView!
collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 60, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Comment: which "Left Aligned collection View Flow Layout" ? on github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contentInset` is NOT `sectionInset`. Here's how you can assign `sectionInset`.

```
if let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 60, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```